# Remote desktop screen sharing not working with Raspberry Pi 5 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: remote-desktop

I've enabled remote desktop and remote control in the sharing options in Ubuntu. I'm using Remmina on the client side (as per this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html), when I input the ip address for the Pi in Remmina it says cannot connect to RDP server. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1492898/edit) and add the following: Are you locally logged into the Raspberry Pi when you try to use remote connection? Is the Raspberry Pi set up to automatically login (as you) when it boots? Is the screen locked (and you locally logged in) when you try? Are you using your login password or the username and password you set up in the "Remote Desktop Sharing" page of settings?